# HTML browser not printing in new line

Tags: html, printing

Need some help with browser printing.

I tried to create a form that have TextArea which insert `\r\n` into database (mongoDB) when type multiple lines of text just fine.

[image: mongo entry]

eg:

```
HP Color LaserJet Pro M252dw Toner (Y)\r\nP/N: CF402A
```

While in browser it goes to new line just fine (using `white-space: pre`) inline style
`td(style="white-space: pre")=`

[image: view in browser]

eg:

```
HP Color LaserJet Pro M252dw Toner (Y)
P/N: CF402A
```

When printing from browser it's goes back into same row as before

[image: print from browser]

eg:

```
 HP Color LaserJet Pro M252dw Toner (Y) P/N: CF402A
```

I tried using pug `.replace('\r\n','<p>')` and it will show `<p>` as a string not as HTML syntax.

I'm using PUG as my template engine run on Node + Express
browser is Chrome.

I'm very new to programming so not sure if I'm doing it wrong or not?

Also this is first time I posting question in Stackoverflow so if I do anything wrong feel free to suggest.

Thank you very much for your answer :)

Comment: Thank you @Michael for your help on editing question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a fix from this link: https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/2583
it seems that I need to put `!` in front of my variables